# PowerShell script to run a reusable workflow on all list Items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

We came across a scenario where we want to run a reusable workflow on all List items in a list. I am not sure if this can be achieved through PowerShell. Can any one please help me to run reusable workflows through PowerShell script on all list items?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are looking for something like this:

```
# URL of the Site
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "https://sharepointsrv/site1"

$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager

# Name of the list
$list = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"]

# Name of the Workflow
$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("On Item Created","en-US")

$data = $assoc.AssociationData
$items = $list.Items
foreach($item in $items)
 {
 $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true)
 }

$manager.Dispose()
$web.Dispose()
#
```

[Click here for details](http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/09/sharepoint-start-workflow-all-items-powershell.html)

Comment: I think it will only work for list workflows but not for Reusable workflows as it is associated to content type. i tried this as it works only on list workflows.

Comment: Please check this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b7f90a3-20ea-4ab2-98ba-7b7cd912874f/deploying-a-reusable-workflow-to-a-list-content-type-using-powershell

Comment: Hmm how to trigger on all Items. It only has attaching workflows to the content types.

Comment: Can any one help me in this regards. I tried triggering normal workflows but not workflow which is associated to content type. I.e Reusable workflow

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script to run a workflow(REUSABLE) which is associated to a content type on all work items.But when we run the below script it will take 5 minutes to start the workflows.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$url = "http://santosh-sharepointexpert.com"
$web = get-spweb $url
$list = $web.Lists["Provide List Name "]
$cTypes = $list.ContentTypes
$cType = $cTypes["Provide content type name"]
$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager


foreach($wf in $cType.WorkflowAssociations)
{
   if($wf.Name -eq "Provide your reusable workflow name ")
   {
    $data = $wf.AssociationData
       #write-host $wf.Name, $wf.Id, $wf.AssociationData          
       foreach($listitem in $list.Items)
       {          
       $wfs = $manager.StartWorkFlow($listitem,$wf,$data,$true)
        #write-host $wfs.InternalState
       }
   }
   $manager.Dispose()
    $web.Dispose()
}
```

Thanks,
Sandy